# How to stop Bash script from exiting on error

Tags: bash, shell, redis

I'm trying to write a Bash script that will check if Redis is running and start it if it's not:

```
ping=$(redis-cli ping)

if [ "$ping" = PONG ]
then
    ECHO "redis response: $ping"
else
    response = $(redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf)
    ECHO "$response"
fi
```

If Redis is running I get the expected `redis response:PONG`
However, if Redis is not running, I get `Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused` and Redis doesn't start.

I think what's happening is the "could not connect" message is treated as an uncaught exception, and is therefore terminating the script.

Is there way to catch that and finish running the script? Is that even the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The following update to the script does exactly what I want it to:

```
ping=$(redis-cli ping)
if [ "$ping" = PONG ]
then
    ECHO "Redis response: $ping"
else
    ECHO starting Redis
    redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
fi
ECHO "$(redis-cli ping)"
```

As Janos correctly pointed out in his second comment, the else statement was executing.

What threw me off was that `ECHO $response` didn't print in the original script. I'm guessing the preceding line, which starts Redis, is an async operation. Therefore, `ECHO $response` was called before Redis was running.

I was also thrown off by the fact that the ping response printed when Redis wasn't running. The script logic dictates that the response should print only if `$ping = PONG`, and it should prepend "Redis Response: ". I'm still not sure why it prints the "failed to connect" message, but whatevs...

Thanks again Janos